How to survive from yajuj and majuj if your broke to go with isa as
How can I survive from
yajuj a majuj if I live in America and I'm broke can I hide or would I die Im not scared but it will hurt so bad when I die I'm broke I can't go with isa in so far away and I'm young I'm even 13 yet  and I can't fight with Imam madhi  whoever reads this I hope you and everyone goes to jannah the highest ameen
